# How do I find what Ids are missing from a table when "those" ids are the result of a query?

Tags: sql

These are my tables:

```
Customer Table
--------------
CUST_ID
SUPPLIER1
SUPPLIER2

Supplier Table
--------------
SUPPLIER_ID
USERID

User Table
----------
USER_ID
```

The rules:

Customers can have multiple suppliers but suppliers MUST be in the user table if they have a customer.

Because all suppliers have to be users, I need to find all used or assigned suppliers that are missing from the user table.

This query gets me all suppliers that are not users

```
SELECT 
    U.*
FROM 
    USER U
LEFT JOIN 
    SUPPLIER S ON S.USER_ID = U.USER_ID
WHERE 
    S.USER_ID IS NULL
```

But how do I get all of the customer's suppliers that are not users?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be correct:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    USER U
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT C.SUPPLIER1, S.USER_ID FROM CUSTOMER C, SUPPLIER S WHERE 
     C.SUPPLIER1 = S.SUPPLIER_ID AND C.SUPPLIER1 IS NOT NULL) 
    S2 ON S2.USER_ID = U.USER_ID
WHERE 
    S2.USER_ID IS NULL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
C.Supplier1
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN Supplier S
ON C.Supplier1 = S.supplier_id

WHERE S.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This solution is so obvious to me now. I don't know why I was fixated with having the user table somehow part of the join ... Now how would this change if I also wanted to check against SUPPLIER2? I already have the Ids I need because I ran this twice, against S1 and S2 but would it be as a single query?

Comment: single query could be a UNION. So SELECT DISTINCT Supplier FROM (query1 UNION query2). And be sure to make the alias (SELECT C.Supplier1 AS Supplier).

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that the Customer table is not normalized, i.e., you have repeated supplier columns in the customer table. You can join the suppliers table twice. e.g.

```
select C.Supplier1, U1.UserID, C1.Supplier2, U2.UserID
from Customer C
left join Supplier S1 on (S1.Supplier_id = C.Supplier1)
left join User U1 on (U1.UserID = C.Supplier1)
left join Supplier S2 on (SS.Supplier_id = C.Supplier2)
left join User U2 on (U2.UserID = C.Supplier2)
where 
   ((not C1.Supplier1 is null) and (U1.UserID is null))
or ((not C2.Supplier1 is null) and (U2.UserID is null))
```

This could easily be more useful to use as the union of a supplier1 missing with supplier2 missing.

Comment: The real problem is that my SQL knowledge needs to improve. But I just need the missing Ids so I can make records in the user table for my suppliers. The other answer provided gives me the Ids I need.

Comment: Actually the other answer will not show you the supplier2 values that are missing, you can simply run the query a 2nd time substituting supplier2 (or make a union of the two queries)